# Send File as an attachment or inline using Spring JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

i have created a simple spring application which sends an email to the user. this seems to be perfectly working with "SimpleMailMessage" (the whole message is going as a plain text). What i want is to send some file as an attachment, so i tried to use javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage but getting some wired Error which i am not able to trace down. Below is my snippet

```
try {
            javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
            helper.setTo(employee.getEmailId());
            helper.setFrom("abc@xyz.com");
            helper.setText(mailMessage, true);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("C:/software/Koala.jpeg"));
            helper.addAttachment("happyBirthday", res);
            mailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Error is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart, have different Class objects for the type n/DataHandler;)V used in the signature
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(MimeMessageHelper.java:997)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(MimeMessageHelper.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(MimeMessageHelper.java:1047)
    at Example1.sendEmail(Example1.java:89)
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the Byte[] type, and you have to convert your file to a Byte[] by using this code :

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

And call this function when you are ready to send mail:

```
public void sendEmail(String to,String from,String sub,String msgBody,byte[] content){

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setFrom(from);
        helper.setTo(to);
        helper.setSubject(sub);
        helper.setText(msgBody);
        helper.addAttachment("MyTestFile.txt", new ByteArrayResource(content));
        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible that i can send the jpg file as an attachment

Comment: sure you can! change `MyTestFile.txt` to `Koala.jpeg` in `helper.addAttachment()`

Comment: i have tried what u have said but same issue is still there

Comment: do you have "activation.jar" in your libs ?

Comment: i removed the activation.jar from the jboss... Apart from this  i changed the attachment to `inputStreamResource` but now i am getting                                `Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call.`

Comment: you have to create a new instance in every using of `InputStreamSource`, use the `new()` method

Comment: i didnt get what u mean. this is what i am doing : `InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/software/Koala.jpg"));
    InputStreamSource source = new InputStreamResource(stream);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this way of making attachment to mail works for me.

```
MimeMesage msg=javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress(email));
msg.setSubject("Subject");

Multipart emailContent=new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart textBodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();
textBodyPart.setText("My multipart");

MimeBodyPart jpgBodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();
jpgBodyPart.attachFile("C:/software/Koala.jpeg");

emailContent.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
emailContent.addBodyPart(jpgBodyPart);

msg.setContent(emailContent);
javaMailSender.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except

```
FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("C:/software/Koala.jpeg"));
```

You can just do this to attach files to messages.

```
helper.addAttachment("happyBirthday", new File("C:/software/Koala.jpeg"));
```

Comment: Still i am getting the same error as described above

Comment: It looks like the problem is probably caused by two versions of the Java Activation Framework. Try to see if removing activation.jar from classpath solves the issue.

Comment: Removed the activation.jar from the jboss as well as removed all specific mail jars compiled in lib folder of the jboss

Comment: Still seeing the same exception ?

Comment: yeah.. still the same issue

Comment: Try to convert your attachement to an InputStream